# how to inherit dialogs correctly in MFC

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I am building a 3d painter in C++ with OpenGL and MFC.
I created dialogs for creating every shape that i have: like cube, cylinder and etc...
My cube class inherits the cylinder class with the difference of amount of stack and slices only.
Hence the CreateCylinder dialog should look the same as the CreateCube dialog.
I was able to inherit it fine, but i have an error that says:

```
Error   6   error C2065: 'IDD_BASEWIN_DIALOG' : undeclared identifier   c:\users\l122\desktop\opengl\opengl\basewindlg.h    19  1   OpenGL
```

This happens every new compilation after some minor code changes.

To fix it, i comment this line:

```
enum { IDD = IDD_BASEWIN_DIALOG };
```

then compile and uncomment the same line, which helps in the next compilation to work fine.

That how i inherited the CreateCylinder dialog class in my CreateCube dialog class:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CreateCube, CreateCylinder)

CreateCube::CreateCube()
: CreateCylinder(this->GetSafeOwner())
{

}

CreateCube::~CreateCube()
{
}


void CreateCube::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    CreateCylinder::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CreateCube, CreateCylinder)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and i also edited this line in the CreateCylinder constructor:

```
CreateCylinder::CreateCylinder(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialogEx(CreateCylinder::IDD, this->GetSafeOwner())
```

The header file:

```
#pragma once
#include "CreateCylinder.h"

// CreateCube dialog

class CreateCube : public CreateCylinder
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CreateCube)

public:
    CreateCube();   // standard constructor
    virtual ~CreateCube();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

I want to know what have i done wrong with the inheritance. is it necessary to send parent's pointer to the base dialog as i did?
And is the error above has to do anything with it?

Comment: Can you please share the header (class declaration), too? Also is `CreateCylinder` your class or part of some library? It doesn't look like a part of MFC , as MFC classes have a `C` prefix, so it should be `CCreateCylinder`.

Comment: i added the header file code to my post. And yes, CreateCylinder is a class, it was my mistake for not naming it right (CCreateCylinderDlg). Is it still possible to change it's name with a wizard (in Visual Studio), without worrying about tons of error that will be related for that change?

Comment: If you didn't mess-up the "wizard markings" in your code, you should be able to change the name of the class with a wizard.

Comment: @srdjan.veljkovic: The class wizard (re-introduced in VS 2010) doesn't need the source code comments to work properly. But renaming the class isn't going to help anyway.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting `#include "resource.h"` on your dialog's `.h` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the scope of the `enum` symbol `IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG`. When you inherit a class, you don't inherit it's "symbol scope", you merely inherit its "members namespace". I'm sure some language lawyer can give a more precise (technically correct) explanation. But, a simple explanation is that you don't inherit symbol - thus enum - definitions. You should be able to access them even if they are in protected scope, though.

So, assuming that `IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG` is used in `CreateCylinder` class to set "its" `IDD`, then, instead of:

```
enum { IDD = IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG };
```

you should write:

```
enum { IDD = CreateCylinder::IDD };
```

I think that the correct wording would be to say that you need the "fully qualified" name here.

This is actually a good thing, and some class libraries use it to play tricks, like enumerating messages supported by a class, and such - see, for example, the `FOX` (widget) toolkit library.

UPDATE:
If you change your declaration as is updated here, thus avoiding the use of `IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG`, it's probable that you won't have problems with `IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG` any more. But, if you still do, the problem would be that `IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG`, since it's declared in `Resource.h`, then, at the time it was used (which is the line for which the error is reported), the `Resource.h` wasn't (properly) included. So, check what is the `.cpp` file that is compiled when your error is reported. Then check the includes in that file. You should clean them up, but, for starters, you may "just" `#include "Resource.h"` at the top (of the `.h` file).

As for the constructor of `CDialogEx`, just pass the parameter along, like this:

```
CreateCylinder::CreateCylinder(CWnd* pParent)
: CDialogEx(CreateCylinder::IDD, pParent)
```

Comment: The IDD_CREATE_CUBE_DLG symbol is actually declared in Resource.h file and not in CreateCylinder class, so i can't use it like you said.
And somehow the compiler gives me an error about the BaseWinDlg's symbol, which is my main dialog from where i can open that other dialogs.
In addition, is sending "this->GetSafeOwner()" to the base class constructor is necessary for inherited dialogs or is it wrong? i have no idea when and if i should do anything about the parents arguments.

Comment: I changed `#include <Resource.h>` to `#include "Resource.h"` and `.cpp` to `.h`

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding resource.h to my base dialog header solved the problem. I just can't understand how it worked flawlessly, before i have added the inherited classes. In both cases this header file wasn't included, so how did it work in a first place?

Comment: May be "Resource.h" was included indirectly?

Comment: See if your Resource.h contains the VS line `//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}`, which will NOT cause a re-compile when it changes due to updated IDs (for example).  This is so that EVERYTHING doesn't recompile due to a dependency of one tweak to the resource.  Usually you could just force re-compile of the ONE module that WAS dependent of that ONE resource tweak.